# How to set specific path permissions using Git?

Tags: git, github

I'm using Git control version system. I want to set custom permission for a specific folder. For example, user1 can commit/read dir1, user2 can only read dir1 and others cannot read it at all. Is that possible and how? Does GitHub support it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The design of Git does not allow this kind of access-control. You can create separate repos for dir1 and dir2, and give appropriate permissions for each of those repos, but you can't restrict access to single directories inside a Git repo.

Comment: Is There any new changes about this topic ? I just moved from TFS to GIT and i want to set permissions for specific folders so that only the authorized people can see and edit code files in that folder

Comment: @AlaaL No, the design of git is still the same. When you can clone a repository, you can see everything in it. It is also _very_ unlikely that this behavior will change.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) to host your git repository, you can setup fine grained access control for branches, or even files.  See: [basic access control](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/basic-admin.html) and [advanced access control](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/git-config.html), path restriction in particular is described [here](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref-2.html).