# Restrict access to file or folder using Git or SVN

Tags: git, svn

I want to use git or svn to manage the source code so each team can only access one part of the source code such as a `controller` folder, a `views` folder or `models` folder.

How can I do that?

Comment: This is in no way related to PlayFramework but instead with Git or SVN.

Comment: Also see this one: [How to set specific path permissions using Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226040/how-to-set-specific-path-permissions-using-git).